"stats" Package not found in RStudio
I have a problem with RStudio. When I start the program, it shows this warning message:
During startup -
Warning message:  
package ‘stats’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found.  
Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...):  
unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R/R-4.4.2/library/stats/libs/x64/stats.dll':  
LoadLibrary failure: The network path was not found.  

I noticed that in R, the stats package is present and works perfectly, while RStudio can't find it. I asked GPT for help, and it recommended several solutions, including uninstalling both R and RStudio and downloading the latest versions, but the issue with RStudio persists.
I installed the latest stable version of R and RStudio, I verified .libPaths() in Rstudio, I checked if Rstudio has the proper permission to access the directory where stats.dll is located, I reinstalled R and R studio. I read another article about this problem on this site, but I didn't find a solution.

What do you mean it works "in R"? Are you referring to R in the command line or R GUI? Which version of R is that using?

I mean I can use the stats package on R.exe (for example I tried the "rnorm" function and it works) however RStudio does not find this package, so no function is recognized. I am using the latest version of R, version 4.4.2

These days I have tried different methods to try to solve it. The method that seems to work is as follows:
after opening RStudio, I write this function
Sys.setenv(PATH=“C:/Program Files/R/R-4.4.2/bin/x64”) and the program recognizes the stats package, and everything seems to work correctly. However, every time I close the program or restart Rstudio, the problem recurs.

In RStudio, go to Tools > Global Options. You'll see a menu where you can select the version of R that RStudio uses. Try setting a different R version to see if the problem persists

If what @gabagool does not work, tell us what your user Makevars says (e.g., C:/Users/You/.R/Makevars)

@gabagool In RStudio/Tools/ Global Options I have only R version 4.4.2 and this version is already selected by Rstudio.

@pachadotdev Sorry, I didn't understand. where can I find this option?
I tried searching C:/Users/You/.R/Makevars, but I didn't find anything.

I mean "you" as in "your username.

I was finally able to resolve the same issue by a simple solution with credit to Du Nguyen here!
just from "C:/Documents" find this file named ".Renviron", which could be hidden, and delete it. Everything will work normal!

I suggest to review that file before deleting it. It may contain environment variables to connect to corporate databases.
